# Linq group by bahaving strangely

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple list of int with three elements, all of them are set to 1000.
If I group this list by values, I still get three elements instead of just one. 
Why?

```
var l = new List<int> {1000, 1000, 1000};
var gr = from i in l
         group i by new
            {
                j = i
            }
            into g1
            from g in g1
            select new
            {
                Id = g1.Key.j
            };

var count = gr.Count(); // <- count is 3!
```

Comment: You're creating a grouping `g1`. Then you're carrying out a projection on each item of that grouping, thereby breaking the group into its constituent parts. The result is what you would expect; 3 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are again projecting the grouped items. It is returning `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,int>>` and you are enumerating `IEnumerable<int>` with `from g in g1` which means you will get the items which are in group `1000` and thus the count `3`.

Following query will give you correct result:-

```
var gr = from i in l
         group i by i
         into g1
         select new
         {
             Id = g1.Key
         };
```

`gr.Count()` will be `1` here since we are projecting the `Key` and not the items inside that group.

**With Method Syntax:**

You currect query is : `l.GroupBy(x => x).SelectMany(x => x)` so it will project all the items in the group thus Count `3`.

If you want to count the Key then: `l.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.Key)` this will return `1` since it will create a single group of `1000`.

Answer (score 3):

Loose the second `from`

```
var l = new List<int> {1000, 1000, 1000};
var gr = from i in l
     group i by new
        {
            j = i
        }
        into g1
        select new
        {
            Id = g1.Key.j
        };

var count = gr.Count(); // <- count is 1!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to achieve this:

```
        var l = new List<pairs>
        {
            new pairs {Index = 0, Value = 1000},
            new pairs {Index = 1, Value = 1000},
            new pairs {Index = 2, Value = 1000},
        };

        var gr = l.GroupBy(a => a.Value);

        var count = gr.Count(); // <- count is 1
```

Where Pairs is a simple POCO:

```
internal class pairs
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `group by` clause gives you the key along with all of the items that are in the group. You are selecting the items and not the key.

For example, try this:

```
var gr = from i in l
         group i by i into g1
         select g1;

var count = gr.Count();
var itemCount = gr.First().Count();
```